# How Do I Implement a Seach Filter on a Database Query and Refresh the Page with Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'll try to simplify this as best as possible. I have a site written in PHP/JavaScript. When I go to a certain page it by default displays a set of filter buttons at the top of the page and an unfiltered data result below that. I can successfully capture the filter results entered and create the appropriate query. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the query back to the database to requery/refresh the data below the filter boxes. The pages are setup as follows:
The page I navigate to is Search.php. In the document.ready script it calls a loadsearchtable function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            /* Load Search Table */
            LoadSearchTable(SearchString, FilterString);
```

Initially the searchstring and filterstring are empty. The LoadSearchTable function calls another page to load the results of the original query:

```
$('div#PostingTable').load('ajax/SearchTable.ajax.php',{SearchString:SearchString,FilterString:FilterString},function(response,status,xhr){
```

The SearchTable.ajax.php page runs the database query and populates an unordered list with the results.

The body of the Search.php is the following code which opens the page which displays the filters and the unorderedlist populated above:

```
<body>
    <?php BodyShell($FileArray,$User,'pages/Search.pages.php'); ?>
</body>
```

The javascript on the search page captures the button click on the Search.pages.php. From this I can get what has been entered in the filters but I don't know how to re-call the loadsearchtable function to go through this process again to change what is displayed in the SearchTable.ajax.php unordered list.

I hope this is clear. If not, please let me know what you need from me to explain it better.

As requested below:
After I build my filter I have the following code:

```
$("div#AJAXDiv").load('ajax/SessionVariable.ajax.php',{VarName:'SearchString',VarValue:$(query)},function(response,status,xhr){
if (status!="success")
{
         /* error with ajax call */ 
    }
else
{

   if(response)
   {
     /* Ajax call ok, php script has issues */
     alert(response);
   }
   else
   {
     /* ajax and php script complete succesfully */
    window.location = "Search.php";
   }
 }
 });
```

This sets a session variable and then calls another instance of itself "Search.php". This time the session variable is populated which should then pass into the LoadSearchTable(SearchString, FilterString) function. However I'm not getting:
1. Any errors
2. Any change in the data that would indicate that the filter has been applied. I've checked the $query prior to populating the session variable and it is correct. I've put alerts within the session variable function (there not all shown above) but am not getting anything and I'm not getting any errors. Just nothing.

Comment: Show the code you have (Javascript) that does the Ajax call. In it's return function, that's typically where you would handle the data returned.

Comment: A solution would be like : onFilterChange -> put your query together -> then send it to ajax -> display return value with javascript. At which step are you having trouble?